# File changes are not reflecting to hard disk and old file is being read every time. How can I get through this?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-16

I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 2016.1.2.

I have a project which contains couple of properties files using which I am handling things such as test run environment, file paths etc.

Now even if I change the particular property such as 'Run.Test.On.Env' which pertains to the environment under test to something like 'UAT' or 'SIT' and run the test suite, still the file is not being changed on hard drive and contains the same old value. And hence tests are being run on old unintended environment. Same issue is observed for XML files in the project which contain user ID's etc.

I have clicked save all, synchronize, invalidated caches, closed the project and imported again, deleted temp files but none of this helped.

I have searched a lot on google and jetbrains.com but no luck until now. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? (clean build)

Comment: @ChickenFeet Yes. I have tried re-building the project couple of times.